# Facebook and Twitter buttons are truncated in prettyphoto

Tags: css, prettyphoto

I am using prettyphoto to display images and video in a gallery. However, the social buttons are getting truncated. I tried changing the `overflow` attribute to `auto` in the prettyPhoto CSS, but all that does is add a scrollbar. This happens regardless the size of the photo or video (see screenshots below). Is there a way to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same problem.
Changed the CSS for the social buttons as so:

```
.pp_social { float: left; margin: 0; width:450px;}
.pp_social .twitter { float: left; width: 90px; }
.pp_social .facebook { float: left; margin-left: 15px; width: 80px; overflow: hidden;}
```

Hope this helps.